# How i can boot Raspbian from USB?

Tags: usb, pi-2, bootloader

I got hands on my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B in just few months and when i used it soo much the SD card got bent in here and it want to snap apart but when i removed it i was trying to rebend it back with a LG LCD panel monitor it dint still boot i think it was removing the case and it bent in here. So i had is 2 GB SD card wich was one of the worst ones to work with the Pi and only OS can be here is Kodi and OSMC. I was looking online to see how to boot up but it din't work beacuse files are outdated so i gone and writing this post to tell how i can make Pi boot from 8 GB USB stick easly not complicated way?
And as well I gone to the research and i think when i unzip the files from Raspbian there was 0.fat i opened it and there been boot files but i dont know where i should put them and i thought that if boot text file that some talked about i think they both should have that set to "root=/dev/sdb" so the SD card and the flash drive should have the same code.
Update :
@Neckbeard2016 i get this error
[image: Error]

your guides dont work I NEED BETTER GUIDES!

Comment: Part of the point of the duplicate is yes, you can use a root filesystem on an external device but you do still need to actually boot the firmware and I believe the kernel from the SD card.  There is no work-around for that.

Comment: It is really hard to follow your multiple questions, answers, edits, and comment that all seem to be about the same issue. While it is true that we strive for an one issue, one question approach it would be helpful if you could try to bundle your problem into one question and focus on the core problem. (See here, same figure that is now posted here again).

Comment: @Ghanima I FIXED IT!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you still need a card as your primary boot partition. If yours is broken, no USB stick can fix that. Seems you really need a new SD card to get your RPi running again.

Take a look at this: http://jonathanmh.com/boot-raspberry-pi-from-a-usb-stick/

Comment: your guide dint work look for the update

Comment: Yeah, no joke. Your card's broken. Get a new one.

Comment: i tried to torture it in windows and it hasnt failed so whos cousing it? not my sd card by the way

Comment: @Neckbard2016 someone posted that Berryboot can boot from usb i think with boot image on sd card or not?

Comment: Well, Berryboot is a boot selection screen, that allows you to put multiple Linux distribution on a single SD card. It won't help you here.

Comment: @Nneckbeard2016 Oh i forgot that 2 gb sd card was fine it was able to run noobs without an error and run osmc and xbmc

Comment: i copied files from raspbian 0.fat with 7zip and i formatted the sd carf to fat32 i think its the bootloader

Comment: I DID IT!!! IN THE INSTRUCTABLES IT WORKED!!!!!